# Will my laptop work with Ubuntu 12.04 LTS?

Tags: 12.04, dell, inspiron, lts

I have a REALLY old Dell Inspiron 8200 laptop with Intel Pentium 4. I was wondering whether it would work. It has a P4 processor, 511mb memory and I have tried the 32-bit version of 12.04. I dont know whether it doesn't support a live CD/DVD (I used a DVD) or if it's because of my using the Toshiba Disc Creator's "Image to Disc" function.

Comment: did the dvd boot properly? did you saw a purple screen? Please configure BIOS to boot from cd/dvd if not.

Answer (score 3):

Ubuntu System Requirements:

```
700 MHz processor (about Intel Celeron or better)
512 MiB RAM (system memory)
5 GB of hard-drive space (or USB stick, memory card or external drive but see LiveCD         for an alternative approach)
VGA capable of 1024x768 screen resolution
Either a CD/DVD drive or a USB port for the installer media
Internet access is helpful
```

Yes, Ubuntu 12.04 should work with your PC.

Try burning the Ubuntu disk with a well known cd creator such as Daemon Tools or Alcohol 120%. Ensure that CD/DVD is on top of your Boot Order list in your BIOS.

Here's a link to documentation where you can read more about system requirements:
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/SystemRequirements

Answer (score 3):

Did you consider trying [Lubuntu](http://lubuntu.net/) - the [LXDE](http://lxde.org/) GUI should be much more responsive on your machine.

Answer (score 1):

You can try and boot up the PC with the live CD/DVD and it should work. My hardware is very similar to yours and this works very efficiently for me.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a pendrive, You can easily turn your pendrive in a Live Ubuntu System to try if it will work. Go to [Pendrive linux](http://www.pendrivelinux.com/) to download the tiny tool, and Read and prepare your pendrive as Live System.

If this method works, Your computer can run Ubuntu. As bettyboo says, You can test Lubuntu - Which uses lightweight Window manager LXDE instead of Compiz.